# Class not found in Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am facing a problem with `maven` dependency.
I have a `maven` project called `DdsInterface`. Inside the `pom.xml` there is this dependency

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.snam.ned</groupId>
        <artifactId>ned-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    ...
```

That is used in a class to import the `NedRestTemplate` object. Everything in the project is working.
Then I build a jar with command `maven clean install` and generate a `ned-dds-interface.jar`.
I then install the library in my local repository `.m2` with command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="target/ned-dds-interface.jar" -DgroupId=ned-dds-interface -DartifactId=ned-dds-interface -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now I want to use this library `ned-dds-interface` in another project call `Portal`. So in the `pom.xml` I created the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ned-dds-interface</groupId>
    <artifactId>ned-dds-interface</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finally I create the war for the project to run in a `Web logic server` using

```
mvn clean install
```

and then deploy the package `Portal` that successfully run on Weblogic. But executing a function I get the following error

```
 Root cause of ServletException.
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/snam/ned/libs/core/NedRestTemplate
    at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.AbstractDdsDaoImpl.<init>(AbstractDdsDaoImpl.java:25)
    at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.DdsFolderDaoImpl.<init>(DdsFolderDaoImpl.java:36)
    at eng.la.controller.DdsController.getFolderInfo(DdsController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you seen the Dependency Hierrarchy in the last project if its is shown there?

Comment: Yes the dds-interface-jar is present in the Maven Dependency. I can correctly call Classes of this library (`ned-dds-interface`). The problem is related to the library (`core`) used inside the library (`ned-dds-interface`).